# NEST C# Elasticsearch query where property is a list

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I'm trying to query the following entity with NEST (.NET elasticsearch wrapper):

```
public class TourIndex
{

    public Guid ProductId { get; set; }

    public Guid[] Periodes { get; set; }

    public Guid[] Countries { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

I want to get all TourIndex object where one of the Countries is guid x.

My index is correct, I can see my TourIndex objects when surfing to             `http://localhost:9200/my-index/_search?pretty=true&q=*:*`

And my query attempt is:

```
System.Func<QueryDescriptor<TourIndex>, QueryContainer> elasticSearchQuery = (q => q.Term(x => x.Countries.First(), myGuidX));

var client = ElasticSearchHelper.CreateNestClient();
var searchResponse = client.Search<TourIndex>(s => s.Query(elasticSearchQuery));

return searchResponse.Documents;
```

Unfortunately I get no results. The respons is Valid but no documents are returned. I've doublechecked there is a valid TourIndex in my index that has my country guid.

An example of an indexed object:

```
{
      "_index" : "my-index",
      "_type" : "tour",
      "_id" : "WRAG141004",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source":{
  "erpTourId": "SNG141004",
  "productId": "9d28694e-d705-e411-93f9-00155d01210a",
  "countries": [
    "01cad5a4-caf4-4d01-88e7-936c0827b13e"
  ],
  "productType": "88e436ff-d605-e411-93f9-00155d01210a",
  "subProductType": "ece1fa1b-d705-e411-93f9-00155d01210a",
  "dayCount": 8,
  "price": 7852,
  "groupCount": 0,
  "isPromotion": true,
  "composition": []
}
```

So myGuidX could be `"01cad5a4-caf4-4d01-88e7-936c0827b13e"` for example.

The analyser/mapping:

```
{
    "live-to-travel-index": {
        "mappings": {
            "tour": {
                "properties": {
                    "available": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "booked": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "capacity": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "composition": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "countries": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "dayCount": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "globusTourId": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "groupCount": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "isPromotion": {
                        "type": "boolean"
                    },
                    "options": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "periodes": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "price": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "productId": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "productType": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "queue": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "subProductType": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I didn't configure anything in c#, this is all default I think.

### Update

I've found a solution to the problem, however I think it's a bad practice.

This code gives me results:

```
elasticSearchQuery = (q => q.Match(m => { m.Query("*" +    query.CountryId.Value.ToString() + "*"); }));
var client = ElasticSearchHelper.CreateNestClient();
var searchResponse = client.Search<TourIndex>(s => s.Query(elasticSearchQuery));
```

My guess is that the wildcards will decrease performance.

Comment: Sorry, but I\m with same problem and can't understand your solution. what's this query in query.CountryId.Value.ToString()?

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide some details on the guid format, your field mappings and analyzers? It's possible that the values are not being searched for/analyzed as you would expect. Also, do you have Kibana/Kopf installed?

Comment: The guid could be "01cad5a4-caf4-4d01-88e7-936c0827b13e", I've edited the description.

Comment: Ok, and what analyzer configuration on this field? It's possible that the entire string is not being recognised as a single token

Comment: I've added the mapping, do you think it's a syntax mistake in my C#?

Comment: What analyzer are you using?